# docker installation in windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

Please I just downloaded and installed Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b and when I tried to run it, I got this error shown in this image. Please I really need help on how to solve it.[image]

Comment: Docker installation on Windows 10 [check article](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-aspnet-core-app/).